# First letter gets cut off

Tags: vb.net

(I am VERY new to coding, so try to keep your answers basic.)

I am making a GamerTag checker that tries to connect to xbox.com/blahblahblah/gamertag and if it returns the gamertag's profile, it says it is taken.

When you type in the first gamertag, it works. But when you type in a second one, it doesn't.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjQOi.jpg

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow
    Console.WriteLine("DiamondHacks's Gamertag Checker!")
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta
    Console.WriteLine("Spaced Gamertags do NOT work :(")
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue
    Console.WriteLine("Just type a word, and it will check if it is available! :)")
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
    Console.WriteLine("Good Luck getting some OG Gamertags :)")
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan
    blahblah()
End Sub

Function blahblah()

    Dim userInput As String = Console.ReadLine
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput) Then
        If checkGamerTag(userInput) = True Then
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, But the Gamertag ""{0}"" is taken!", userInput)
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan
        Else
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
            Console.WriteLine("The gamertag ""{0}"" is not taken! :D Better get it before I do!", userInput)
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan
        End If
    End If
    Console.Read()
    blahblah()
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan
End Function

Private Function checkGamerTag(ByVal gamerTag As String) As Boolean
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(gamerTag) Then
        Try
            Dim callBack As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(String.Format("http://live.xbox.com/en-GB/Profile?gamertag={0}", gamerTag))
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(callBack) Then
                If Not callBack.Contains("Ooops! What happened to this page?") Or callBack.Contains(gamerTag) Then Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch : Return False : End Try
    End If
End Function

End Module
```

Comment: The answer Kenogu gave is correct, you also have declared a Function blahblah which is actually a Subroutine since you are not returning anything from it and should be declared as Sub.

Answer (score 5):

Your call to `Console.Read()` before your call to `blahblah()` is chewing up the first character of the next line.